# maximum call stack size exceed when try to do a counter in react js

Tags: reactjs, recursion, react-hooks, use-effect

Got maximum call stack size exceed when try to do a counter in react js.
I am using a functional component to create a counter. That will start from 0 and it will increase by 10 every time until it reaches the maximum limit.
**here is my code**

```
const [initialCount, setInitialCount] = useState(0);
useEffect(() => {
  const handleScoreAnimate = () => {
    if (initialCount >= maxLimit) {
      setInitialCount(maxLimit);
    } else {
      setInitialCount(initialCount + 10);
      handleScoreAnimate();
    }
  }
  if (initialCount === 0) {
    handleScoreAnimate();
  }
}, [initialCount]);
```

Comment: Do you want to show delay while updating your state?

Comment: like digital speedometer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is due to recursive call to `handleScoreAnimate` function in `useEffect`.

You might get better solution to this, but you can make use of `setTimeout` to achieve this,

```
useEffect(() => {

   const timer = setTimeout(()=>{
      setInitialCount(c => c >= maxLimit ? maxLimit : c + 10)
   },1000)  //timeout can be adjusted according to your need

   //This is to clear the timeout when component unmounts
   return () => clearTimeout(timer);

}, [initialCount]);
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-yz94sf)